# Check duplicate values from database on button click event

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, ajax

I have a requirement, where I want to check whether user is not inserting the same `Project`, `Survey No` again and again.

**It should fire an alert if it enters the same combination twice on button click**

Here is my HTML:-

```
<td class="label">
                    Project :
                </td>
                <td class="field" style="width: 10%;">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject" runat="server" Width="80%" AutoPostBack="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProject_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="label">
                    Survey No :
                </td>
                <td class="field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurvey1" runat="server" Width="80%" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
```

I tried the below link, but it was not for the combination. It was just for one textbox value, So it was not working in my case.

[check duplicate data with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337844/check-duplicate-data-with-javascript)

Kindly let me know how to deal with the combination part

Comment: are you asking how to send two values? instead of one?

Comment: @Mysterio11: yes, for the checking the combination of two values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have made a few changes to the answer linked by you

```
    var projval=$('#ddlProject').val();
    var survey=$('#txtSurvey1').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "YourPage.aspx/DoesDataExist",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        proj :projval, // the names of the properties must match with the parameters in the backend function
        surv :survey
       }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
     success: function(msg) {
    if(msg.d) {
        // This is a duplicate, alert user with message
        // Block the server-side click from happening with return false;
        return false;
      }
   }
  });
```

this is the backend webservice

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static bool DoesDataExist(string proj, string surv )
  {
      SqlCommand commandrepeat1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from table where project="+proj+" and Survey="+surv+" ");
      commandrepeat1.Connection = objconnection;
      objconnection.Close();
      objconnection.Open();
      SqlDataReader drmax1;
      drmax1 = commandrepeat1.ExecuteReader();
      drmax1.Read();
      if (drmax1.HasRows)
      {
          objconnection.Close();
          return true;
      }

      objconnection.Close();
      return false;
}
```

Comment: let me try and check with your answer :)

Comment: I am getting error as **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected** at line `var projval=$("#ddlProject").val();`

Comment: replace $("#ddlProject").val() with $('<%="#"+ddlProject.ClientId%>') and try

Comment: i resolved that error, but now getting error as **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

Comment: tell me have you included the jquery library?

Comment: yes, here it is `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: this error usually comes if you have not included jquery properly or if you have done it twice

Comment: if I take `data: "{'codeValue': $('#txtSurvey1').val()}",`  it does not gives me the error

Comment: stringify of JSON.stringify.should be lower case. it was a mistake. It was upper case S before

Comment: now, I am getting error as `The connection is closed` . :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122383/discussion-between-mysterio11-and-stack).

Comment: I am on chat, please come their. we are almost near to my solution